# How correctly release UITabController

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

This may sound a newbie question ... but however I'm new to iOS development.

I've created `UITabController` object programmatically like this.

```
mTabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
...
mTabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tabBarItems];
[tabBarItems release];
```

And releasing mTabBarController in dealloc like this.

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [mTabBarController release];
}
```

Now my question : will I get a memory leak ? When I assign value t viewController the ref count of tabBarItems is still 1. When I release mTabBarController does it also release all its viewcontrollers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the tab controller owns an array of view controllers (and everything in an array is retained). You're not creating a leak as long as you properly release or autorelease the items you're adding to the tabBarItems array.

It really helps to think of object relationships as ownerships.

Comment: May I ask also about this structure 
mTabBarController.viewControllers = tabBarItems;
[tabBarItems release];
Application was working correctly ... But I'm not getting if I assign this way to viewControllers it will get the address of tabBarItems ... and then I release tabBarItems ... So why It was workin correctly ? 
May it be just an incident that the memory allocated for tabBarItems was not reused ... ?

Comment: Exactly! Just make sure when you add each item to the array that that item is released if necessary, too.

Comment: When you assign viewControllers = tabBarItems, the tab view controller retains the array. The array isn't cleared when you release it because it's been retained by the tab bar controller. 

So, the tab bar controller owns the array, and the array owns each of the items in it, so you're safe.

Comment: No, the second time should be 1. It's 1 because you created it. Then you pass it as viewControllers and it becomes 2. Then you release it, so it becomes 1 again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4639/discussion-between-ash-furrow-and-deimus)

Comment: OK, sorry for the confusion. It's because the viewControllers property of UITabBarController is a copy property, so it doesn't retain your array, it copies it.

Comment: Then why the retainCount of tabBarItems is 1 after releasing it ?

Answer (score 1):

UITabBarController should never be placed as the child of another ViewController, so you will always have to release it in dealloc. If your TabBarController's view is the childview of your application's window, it's ok not to release it in dealloc since the only time dealloc will ever get called is when your program is closing, in which case your controller will be released anyways. However, some people like to release it in dealloc anyways just to keep their code consistent. What you're doing is fine.

Comment: mTabBarConroller is no a view ... I've done following [self.window addSubView : mTabBarController.view] but releasin mTabBarController right after addSubView causes application to crash when switching between tabs ... I think it is this kind of problem, rigth ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937767/does-uiviews-addsubview-really-retain-the-view

Comment: Wow, it's too early in the morning.. ignore everything i said before... it was ALWAYS wrong since UITabBarController should never be the child of any other viewcontroller. I fixed the post though.