# UIScrollView Custom ViewController

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, exc-bad-access, viewcontroller

I have an odd situation. I want user to choose a category by clicking an button inside UIScrollView. Here's the relevant code of page view controller (the one containing UIScrollView made with IB):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    uiScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake([[SawData shared].categories count]*320,480);
    int i = 0;
    for (NSString* key in [SawData shared].categories) {
        Baton *b = [[Baton alloc] initWithNibName:@"Baton" bundle:nil];
        b.view.frame = CGRectMake(i++*320, 0, 320, 480);
        [uiScroll addSubview:b.view];
        [b release];
    }
}
```

Baton is new UIViewController subclass containing only one button with touchUp action that prints some log info using NSLog. With this code I get the Batons properly arranged side by side. Problem is that clicking the button gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS as Batons view controller is released.

If i remove the [b release]; line I have Batons overlayed one over other as i++ * 320 is giving same result (which i checked and its correct). In this case click on button is working.

Thank you for help!

iOS SDK 4.3

EDIT 1:
After much trial and error, I have managed to find out whats happening. Its 320px width of controls. If i changed them to 321 or 319 all works as it should. I dont need to release the controller to image fill the UIScrollView content AND clicking the button works. What the hell is this?

Answer (score 0):

This might be the reason.

```
Baton *b = [[Baton alloc] initWithNibName:@"Baton" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

You should also make sure that the UIButton is initialized before you click on it. You can do this easily with the debugger.

Take a look here

[Does UIView's addSubview really retain the view?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/937767/640618)

Comment: I am sorry but this didn't help.